# Display negative value as 0 in excel using custom format

Tags: excel, format

I am trying to display negative numbers as a 0 value within a cell. I do not want to use excel formulas as various cells have unique formulas. How do i do this using the custom format in excel?

Comment: Number format: `General;"0"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
0_.;"""0";"0"_0 makes any negative number 0
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out in a comment above, the custom number format allows you to format a cell's according to its content.

So, you can - [as pointed out on Microsoft's website](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4) - format any cell for:

1. positive numbers,
2. negative numbers,
3. zeros, and
4. text

So, to format positive numbers with two decimal places and a separator for thousands you should use `#,##0.00`. If you want to format negative numbers differently then you should add the format for negative numbers after that (separated with a semi-colon) `#,##0.00;#,[red]##0.00`. If you wish to format yet again zeros differently then you should add that after the two aforementioned like so `#,##0.00;#,[red]##0.00;"-"`. In this case, zeros will be shown with a simple `-` instead of a zero and negative numbers will be shown alike positive numbers but in red color. Finally, you can expand the **number format** for any cell by one more content type: text. If you want to replace any text in a cell with `here is text` then you can do so by adding `#,##0.00;#,[red]##0.00;"-";"here is text"`.

For more information read Microsoft's article on custom number formats here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4

So, in summary you are probably looking for something like this:

```
General;"0"
```

<sub>*This answer was originally posted as a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39288533/display-negative-value-as-0-in-excel-using-custom-format/39289086#comment65911410_39288533) by @axel-richter: feel free to repost this answer as your own, and leave me a comment so I'll delete this copy. This kind of answer has been stipulated for [questions with no answers, but issue solved in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments).*</sub>

Comment: Perrrfect, Thank you